# H Bridge Control using Raspberry PI / Micro controller

Tags: microcontroller, transistors, digital-logic, raspberry-pi

I am looking for input on this circuit that I have designed. I am currently working on a project called the Net-EEL RC Car. It is an RC car that will be controllable using Network Socket Servers / Clients. Therefor, you will be able to control an RC car sitting at the network server with a gaming steering wheel.

I am trying to design my H Bridge circuit to control the speed and direction of the motor I will be using. I am using the Raspberry PI as my Data Receiver and will be using the PI to control the H Bridge.

Here is a schematic I have designed.
[image]

So far I have the following

1. Raspberry PI will generate PWM signals to control a BJT. This BJT is used to control a Mosfet. I have chosen a BJT due to the VGS requirements of a Mosfet. It requires me to supply a gate voltage that is equal to the source I am controlling, therefor I am using a BJT to apply the source voltage to the gate of the Mosfet.

   I have looked into to using Logic Level Mosfets, which will remove the need to use   BJT's in order to provide a proper gate voltage to the Mosfets.
2. I also have a Micro controller that will be used to monitor the voltage level of the battery, I am running the battery voltage through a voltage divider so I can properly read the voltage level using a 0-5V ADC.

I believe that my circuitry will work, however I am looking for some input from the community.

Thanks in advance.

** **EDIT** **
I have added the resistors between the Gate of the Mosfets to ground in order to turn off the transistors if there is no signal present at the BJTs base.

** **EDIT 2** **
I have also considered using logic levels mosfets instead of needing a BJT.

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: you have nothing to turn OFF the NTypes or turn ON the PTypes. This circuit will not really work

Comment: @JonRB If I understand what you are saying, It seems like I have missed the resistors between the Gate of the mosfets to ground in order to turn them off if there is no signal applied.

Comment: @Null No, there isnt a specific questions. I am more so looking for inputs from the community on the design and whether it would work.

Comment: Very pretty diagram. I especially like your use of colour.  Nice and eye catching.

Comment: You now have slow turnOFF for the NTYPE and slow turnON for the PTYPE. You do not have any bulk capacitance for your "DClink" the Hbridge needs to be presented with a voltage source.

Comment: @Majenko Thanks, I try to make my schematics easily readable. I find it makes it more welcome especially when trying to read a circuit that you've never seen!

Answer (score 1):

Why are you not driving the motors directly by [L293D](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/l293d.pdf)? Its a reliable working H-Bridge and also the it can make your circuit less troublesome..

There are other ICs avaliable for H-Bridge based on persons requirements..

Comment: I am building an H bridge because It is a requirement to build your circuits instead of using ICs. Not like it is difficult to build a proper working H bridge